# Problem with GeoServer WFS URL

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, wfs, getfeature

I am having problem when I am Requesting following URL in GeoServer

/geoserver/wfs?REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&typename=Final&propertyname=name&service=WFS&

I am getting following error:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http:///geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain connection: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Unable to obtain connection: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. Connection refused: connect
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Can any one help in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check that your postgres database is working properly and the DataStore definition in GeoServer is correct: port, host name, etc.

GeoServer is telling you that it can't connect to to postgres.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer i have solved this problem and your answer is right.